# Is it possible to decrease the speed of a standard servo motor?

Tags: servo

I have TowerPro SG-5010 and its speed is 0.17 sec/60° at 4.8V and 0.14 sec/60° at 6V.

Just to be sure, is it possible to further decrease the rotation speed?

Comment: For a small reduction in speed you can experiment with supplying lower voltage to the servo. But at some point its controller chip will stop working. You could open it and add 1 or 2 ohms in series with the motor. Any more than that would probably stall it. Probably the best way would be to add an extra stage of gearing (which reverses direction, so reverse the motor connections too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the given speed would be "maximum" speed.

To decrease the speed of a regular motor you would use PWM to lower the voltage.
But servomotors (usually) work with a fixed width (20ms?) to indicate their rotation (1ms 0degrees, 4ms 360degrees?)

The illustration below shows the difference between PWM and servo control.

Image at the right is the servo signal, you should increase the ON time from 1ms to 4ms, the speed at which you do this will be your servomotor speed.

You should check the datasheet of your servo-motor to be sure.

[image: http://nickviera.com/electronics/cobra_mcu/drawings/xl_pwm_vs_servo.png]

Comment: I'm actually not sure, you should test it before accepting it as an answer. Or can someone atleast verify that this is the right way to do it?

Comment: That is **not** how stepper motors work.

Comment: But is it how servo motors work?

Comment: oh, hah. I re-read the question and realized it wasn't asking about stepper motors. Late nights == mind not working :(

Answer (score 6):

The way I reduce the rotation speed of a standard servo is to just not rotate the servo as fast.

Instead of changing the angle straight from, say, 0° directly to 90°, change the angle in small increments at the speed you want.

Even better is to use a logarithmic or exponential acceleration / deceleration schema.

Say you want to to from 0° to 90°.  First go from 0° to 1°.  Then from 1° to 3°.  Then from 3° to 6°, then to 10° etc, until you reach a top desired speed - then reduce the distance you are changing with each "step".

So for each "tick" of your control clock you would step by (as an example) 1°, 2°, 3°, 4°, 5°, 5°, ...  5°, 5°, 4°, 3°, 2°, 1°.

Another useful method is the "divide by 2" schema.

For that you simply move by half the target distance with each "tick".  So for a 90° rotation you first move to 45°.  That leaves 45° left to move, so you move 22.5°.  You then have 22.5° left to move, so you move half that at 11.25°, etc, until you have reached your destination.  It makes for a fast start to the movement, with a nice smooth deceleration to the target angle.

These methods are great for reducing the inertia and momentum induced stresses on the load of the servo motor.

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the speed of a TowerPro SG-5010 servo motor
like this

`import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
p = GPIO.PWM(12, 100)
t = 0.2
r = 20 
p.start(r)
while True:
        for i in range(5,r):
                p.ChangeDutyCycle(i)
                print(i)
                time.sleep(t)
        for i in range(r,5,-1):
                p.ChangeDutyCycle(i)
                print(i)
                time.sleep(t)`

Comment: Just posting some code with no explanation does not meet the standards of an answer on a stack exchange site such as this.